# roots and embeddings

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field, can we always find an embedding let $\rho:G\rightarrow GL_n$, that sends a Borel pair $(B_G,T_G)$ to $(B,T)$ and center to center,

such that the image in $X^{*}(T_G)$ of the simple roots of GL_n is included inside the positive span of simple roots of $G$?

This question is in fact related to functoriality for the wonderful compactification (see Thm. 4.7):
https://www.ias.ac.in/public/Volumes/pmsc/109/03/0241-0256.pdf

Comment: If the center of $G$ is not cyclic, clearly you can not do that.

Comment: I would already be satisfied with G adjoint. In fact, a case by case check shows that it is ok for classical groups, so I would like to know what happens for exceptional types.